# Counting interactions with linked nodes [netlogo]

Tags: networking, hyperlink, netlogo

My model has links with defined duration, and I am trying to register the new links and the old ones in two different vectors.

The Problem: When I run the simulation the new links are stored correctly, but the old ones appear duplicated in the csv file. I am making a mistake at some point and I really need some help. If there is a more elegant way of doing it, I appreciate the tips! Thanks all for the collaboration!

```
ifelse not link-neighbor? myself
        [       
        create-new-links-with partner in-radius 0.1
        ask new-links
         [
        set registernew []
        set link-duration max (list duration maxduration)
        set link-creation time:copy dt
        set link-end time:plus link-creation link-duration "year"
        set link-installment invtransf
        set meets 1    
        set registernew ([(list link-creation link-duration link-end link-installment meets end1 end2) ] of new-links)
              
        add-records                
        set breed old-links
          ]
         ]
         [
          ask old-links
          [
          set registerold [ ]
          set meets time:copy dt
          set registerold ([(list link-creation link-duration link-end link-installment meets end1 end2) ] of old-links)
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked this, but I suspect that the problem is that you have bidirectional links WITH, not unidirectional links TO or FROM,  so the old-links get reported by each end separately which duplicates their presence in the list.

Again I haven't tried this but you might set a flag-variable in each link at the start of each large pass, like,  reported? to false,  and then deep in the loop when you are about to report it see if it's already been reported and if not, go ahead ( report and set the flag ) and if it has,  don't report it again but interrupt the run with a user-message and examine what just happened.

Wade